How to bind multiple controls to a single model value in Avalonia UI MVVM without making the model object contain [ObservableProperty]
When using MVVM Community Toolkit, C#, .NET and Avalonia UI, I find myself making my model objects observable because it solves a recurring problem that I encounter when editing a model value from multiple controls.
However, I think that is bad practice. There is a GitHub Repo supporting this question, https://github.com/danieljfarrell/QuestionApp1, it's an Avalonia UI application that demonstrates the issue.

In a nutshell...
I like to define model objects with simple properties,
namespace QuestionApp1.Models
{
    public class VolumeSetting
    {
        public int Volume { set; get; }

        public VolumeSetting(int volume)
        {
            Volume = volume;
        }
    }
}

A single control can edit it's value fine.
However, I often want multiple controls to be able to bind-to and mutate the value of the model object's attributes.
In this case I tend to make the model object observable,
public partial class ObservableVolumeSetting : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    public int volume;

    public ObservableVolumeSetting(int volume)
    {
        Volume = volume;
    }
}

The change notification will now keep values synchronised even when the value mutation occurs from multiple controls.
I have heard that this bad practice!

Can someone let me know the dangers of making model objects observable. It seems such a pragmatic solution to this particular problem
Can you suggest a better approach?

Very grateful for your advice.

You've created a problem for yourself with self-imposed rules. Rarely does one find a "volume" "class"; one is more like to find it as a "property" of  a class; e.g. "device" or measurement; which can then fill a need  standing on its own. And paired (in the same UC) with a "readout" of some sort; which is usually a requirement. A "volume" by itself is not a useable component. Unless it's an actual potentiometer.

I completely agree. You have focused on the toy example rather than the question.

My response was to the question of having lots of disjointed controls versus one cohesive one. I believe in granularity ... and real life examples.

Observable properties are just properties with a specialized change notification event.  Depending on the intended use of the model, there is nothing wrong with using this approach.  It isn't a bad practice at all to use events or even Callback methods in the model, that's how it supposed to be done in MVVM.  There are only 3 real important tenants in MVVM:

The View and the Model can not communicate directly without the ViewModel.
The View may only make direct calls to the ViewModel, but the ViewModel must use events to communicate back. (i.e. The ViewModel is oblivious to the presence of the View).
The ViewModel may make direct calls to the Model, but the Model must use events (or callbacks) to communicate back. (i.e. The Model is oblivious to the outside world.)

What you do have to be mindful of is not allowing the view to subscribe to these events.  If the view is directly aware of the model, you've lost the isolation that MVVM gives you.
Often times when I need that particular behavior, I will use my own events rather than implement INotfiyPropertyChanged.  While the overall behavior is no different, the view can't really react to any other events (assuming binding), so it discourages the improper use of the model.  The downside to this approach, is you can't use the convenient generator attributes in the CommunityToolkit to do this.  However, there is nothing wrong with implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on any class.

Making your model objects observable might seem like a convenient solution to handle updates from multiple controls, but it's often considered bad practice in the context of MVVM for a few reasons.
The main issue with making your models observable is that it tightly couples your model to the UI framework and introduces unnecessary complexity. Models should ideally represent your application's data and business logic, while the ViewModel acts as an intermediary between the model and the view. Mixing UI-specific logic like INotifyPropertyChanged (wich is done by your inheritance of ObservableObject) into your models breaks the separation of concerns.
Instead of making your models observable, you might want to keep them simple, and move the change notification logic to the view model. Here's how i personally would do it:
Plain model:
public class VolumeSetting
{
    public int Volume { get; set; }
    public VolumeSetting(int volume)
    {
        Volume = volume;
    }
}

ViewModel for Notifications:
public class VolumeSettingViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private readonly VolumeSetting _volumeSetting;

    public int Volume
    {
        get => _volumeSetting.Volume;
        set
        {
            if (_volumeSetting.Volume != value)
            {
                _volumeSetting.Volume = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Volume));
            }
        }
    }

    public VolumeSettingViewModel(VolumeSetting volumeSetting)
    {
        _volumeSetting = volumeSetting;
    }
}

You may also use some 3rd party libraries, like you did with ObservableObject. I think you're using CommunityToolkit?

Making a model observable does not tightly couple your model to the UI. Having the model make direct calls to the View tightly couples the model to the UI. INotifyPropertyChanged is not UI specific either, it's completely agnostic.  The problem with moving your notifications to the ViewModel is that depending on the need, you may have more than one ViewModel using the same model and you may need to notify the other ViewModels of a change from the outside.  A ViewModel is a translator for a specific view, there should 1 ViewModel for each View (no sharing), but with models, that's not the case.
